# Is there a function to finish a UIviewcontroller like in android?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In android you can call the method `finish()` and the activity closes. Is there something similar in swift?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not quite. In iOS land you have to more explicitly call `viewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` if your view controller is a modal or one of the various dismissal methods on UINavigationController if your viewController was pushed on to the screen.

In **Swift 3** this function is:

```
viewController.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple Elegant Solution, write the below line to dismiss your current View Controller

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```